# How to install default 20.04 bgrt plymouth?

Tags: boot, gnome, kubuntu, plymouth

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 from canonical iso. I install kubuntu-desktop from scratch after removing gnome-shell. Now I wanna revert back with the default Gnome DE. I have been successful pretty much, except with the plymouth.

The best thing about 20.04 LTS is the BGRT, the spinning wheel and the ubuntu integrated with manufacturer logo. I had removed `bgrt.plymouth`. I tried to install other like `ubuntu-logo` or `ubuntu-gnome-logo` but I actually want BGRT to be restored without reformatting the system.

Would anyone mind to help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this...

If you did remove/purge plymouth-theme-spinner then, as @norbert suggests:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-spinner
```

If you didn't remove/purge plymouth-theme-spinner then just do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Then select the bgrt option.

Reboot. Be happy!

Answer (score 2):

The search on packages.ubuntu.com gives exact [package name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bgrt.plymouth). You have to reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-spinner
```